# Scaling pixelart bitmap creates abomination

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to scale this player twice it size with animation: 
[image]

I used this code:

```
if(sprite.getWidth()<effected.getWidth()*2){
                sprite=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sprite, sprite.getWidth()+5, sprite.getHeight()+5, false);
}
```

inside a timer.

**result with filter (horrible quality):**
[image]

*(picture is rotating so its hard to catch it normal - sorry for that)*

**picture without filter (This will give me nightmares):** [image]

what can I do to change the size of the bitmap with animation while keeping good quality?

Comment: I'd normally say "Start with a bigger sized sprite and scale that one DOWN" (since scaling DOWN works MUCH better than scaling UP - take this concept as an Universal Law of the Physics). But The image you have is pixellated in it's "normal" state, so...

Comment: @Der Golem I like the idea, I'll try it now. edit: actually that wont work because i will have to scale it down and when ill scale it up again it will do the same problem.

Comment: Why would you need to **scale it up** *again*? The idea is that you *already have it* **for free**. You would only scale it DOWN once. And have **both** the small and the big versions handy, without any UPscaling.

Comment: @Der Golem because you forget i'm trying to make it scale up with an animation, if I wanted just to make it appear bigger it would work, but because i'm trying to animate it growing having the result won't change the between translation.

Comment: Oh, I see. My bad. Maybe you could prepare all the scaled images in advance and then animate them as a FrameAnimation, instead of a ScaleAnimation.

Comment: As a **last resource**, you could use a prepared animated GIF.

Comment: @DerGolem I have a believe that there is a fix for it, ill see what I will do if i wont be able to find direct solution.